# jQuery button click does not work in Rails 3.2.2 rendered partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Here is my partial (_lookup.html.erb) that has the append button

```
<div class="lookupbtnrow">
    <button id="lookupappend" type="button" class="ui-corner-all">Append</button>
</div>
```

Here is the test jquery function, in lookup.js

```
$("#lookupappend").click(function(){
     alert("testing...");
});
```

If I put the **div** contents in the index page, the button click works fine, but when I put the **div** contents into the partial, the button does not work at all.

Do I have to put a <%= javascript_include_tag %> in the partial?

Comment: Are you using running that jQuery after the DOM loads?

Comment: It works, good old programmer error, changed a tag's id to a class.

Comment: I take it back, it works cause i moved the button to the index page.  Now .hover doesnt work on any of the td tags in the partial.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if the issue stemmed from the `dom ready` function only applying to the index document, and not applied to loading the partials, leading to race conditions. Try putting the javascript link in to the partial and see what happens. Or bind the click handler into a function and call that function when the partial loads.

Good Luck
-Brian